# Cláusula WHERE com Array PHP-MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com o seguinte código, mas não está funcionando e não encontro o erro.
Preciso exibir as 3 linhas (123), que s encontram em `$fetch['list_carac']`.

```
<?php
include 'conect.php';

$sql = "SELECT list_carac FROM select_carac WHERE id_produto = 1";
$exec = $con->query( $sql ) or exit( $con->error );
$fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exec); 
$fetch = str_replace( ",", "", $fetch);

echo($fetch['list_carac']);//aqui a saída é 123

foreach($fetch as $value){

$sql =  "SELECT nome_carac FROM carac WHERE id_carac = $value";

$exec = $con->query( $sql ) or exit( $con->error );

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exec);

echo $row["nome_carac"];
}
?>
```

Se eu tirar o `foreach` e acrescentar o `id` manualmente ele me retorna o registro que se encontra no campo `nome_carac`. Caso contrário não dá erro , mas só mostra a 1º saída`echo($fetch['list_carac']);//aqui a saída é 123`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se tem certeza que no DB está sempre com vírgula, basta isso:

```
$sql = 'SELECT nome_carac FROM carac WHERE id_carac IN ('.$lista.')';
```

Aplicado ao seu código:

```
<?php
    include 'conect.php';

    $sql = 'SELECT list_carac FROM select_carac WHERE id_produto = 1';
    $exec = $con->query( $sql ) or die( $con->error );
    $fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exec); 

    $lista = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $fetch['list_carac'] );
    $sql = 'SELECT nome_carac FROM carac WHERE id_carac IN ( '.$lista.')';
    $exec = $con->query( $sql ) or exit( $con->error );

    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exec) ){ 
       echo $row["nome_carac"];
    }
?>
```

Eventualmente, se a lista não for só numérica, precisa de uma pequena sanitização (com aspas):

```
    $caracteres = explode( ',', $fetch['list_carac'] );
    foreach( $caracteres as $caractere ) {
        $lista .= "'".mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $caractere )."',";
    }
    $lista = rtrim( $lista, "," );
```

Comment: Se tiver algum erro bobo de sintaxe avise que eu já arrumo.

Comment: Estilo o Voleio do Bebeto em 94, e é goll !!! Certim patrão vlw ai...